# iPhone didreceivememorywarning strategy

Tags: iphone, ios

If i have a array of employees for example in my viewcontroller. Then I get the notification of low memory and the app is also not the active one.

At this point I should save the list of employees in a DB right ? so that when the user reactivate the app again, it will go through the viewDidLoad and from here I can reload the data from the DB?

Is this a good strategy?

I'm fairly new into iPhone dev.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should save any unsaved changes as soon as your app enters the background. Your app could be terminated at any point in the background without ever receiving any notifications of any kind. If your data isn't saved, it will be lost when the user restarts the app.

With regard to memory warnings, these are more likely to happen in the foreground. Once your app is in the background, it is suspended and won't get any notifications. If your app is running under iOS 5 or earlier then a memory warning could result in a view controller's viewWillUnload method being called. When that view controller needs to be displayed again, its viewDidLoad will be called again. Under iOS 6, this doesn't happen anymore. viewWillUnload is deprecated.

Comment: So in case of memory warning, I should nil my array of employees right? to free up memory? In that case, I should save it in the store before no? So that when viewDidLoad is called, I can reload the whole list of employee?

Comment: If you get a memory warning, you can take any steps you feel are appropriate to help reduce your memory usage. Saving unsaved data is always a good idea. But if you just have a few names in memory there is little savings. If you have megabytes of data in memory that you can clear up and reload again when needed, then that's a good idea. Keep in mind that viewDidLoad may not be called. It will only be called if viewWillUnload is called first due to memory issues. And this doesn't happen under iOS 6.